# Deep linking for Square mobile app and Register API

Tags: square-connect

I wanted to know if there are any custom URL scheme for ios/android that I can redirect my app's user to a specific screen in the Square Register app.

Are there any deep linking url schemes that redirects to the Square Register app and show a specific transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a way to deep link into specific views of the Square Register app, but that is something we are looking into.

Comment: Any update on deep linking? Is it possible to redirect to the Square POS app on iOS/Android without initiating a transaction with the POS API? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, still not possible, but keep your eyes out for some new features soon!

Comment: @tristansokol it possible now?